# Ignoring spring mvc JSR-303 validations for selective entity fields

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have spring4 mvc application to save an Address entity, code bit as follows.

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addAddress", method = POST)
public String registerComplaint(@Valid @ModelAttribute final Address address, final BindingResult resultBinder) {
    if (resultBinder.hasErrors())
        return "addAddress";
     addressService.addAddress(address);
    return "redirect:myAddress";
}
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
  @NotNull
  private String street;

  @NotNull
  private String pin;

  @NotNull
  private String createdBy;

  ........
}
```

My form conatins only **street** and **pin** as field, where as **createdBy** should be set by me after validating the other form values.

Here the problem is spring JSR303 validation support is validating a field  ie **createdBy** which i don't want to validate by spring mvc.

How can i instruct spring mvc not to validate these kind of optional fields while using **@Valid** annotation.

Is there any way i can skip fields like this using spring mvc ?

Answer (score 2):

Validation is mainly for user input. Since you will be setting `createdBy` yourself, just do so before saving it (e.g [@PrePersist](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event)), or have a new Date as a default value. If you need to enforce a constraint for createBy, you can do so at the schema level.

```
@Column(nullable=false, ...)
private String createdBy = new Date();
```

Comment: Thanks, its true but if we want to JPA provider level validation for example to kick off hibernate validation, we need to have validation annotation rite? In that case this methodology wont work. My question is living all fields with validation annotation is there anyway we can instruct spring mvc to skip some selective fields

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to read up on [Validation Groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html). This lets you use different validators depending on the "scenario"
2. Use Spring's [@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) annotation to use groups
3. If you don't protect the createdBy field, a user can change it by altering the POST variables. See [DataBinder.setDisallowedFields()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html)
4. Conceptually, how is a pin related to an address?

It sounds like you want to use a Form Backing Object here (a regular non-JPA POJO made just for a form), and copy values to your real entities.

Comment: Thanks, Validation group is too cumbersome better i could think of customizing LocalValidatorFactoryBean. setDisallowedFields i'm already setting based on what field i'm exposing to form and not (i have multiple form for the same entity which exposes fields optionally). That Address entity is just a mock no concept applied. I'm afraid i could go in non-JPA just for this simple validation.